# How to shorten block of code for bingo checker? (beginner question)

Tags: java

I'm making a checkwinner class that checks 4 arrays for a bingo win, and it is wayyyy too long. Any way i can shorten it? I know you can use a for loop, but I have no idea how.thank you in advance!

```
public static boolean checkWinner(String[][] card, String[][] card2, String[][] card3, String[][]card4) {
    if ((card[0][0] == card[0][1] && card[0][1] == card[0][2] && card[0][2] == card[0][3] && card[0][3] == card[0][4]) || (card[1][0] == card[1][1] && card[1][1] == card[1][2] && card[1][2] == card[1][3] && card[1][3] == card[1][4])|| (card[2][0] == card[2][1] && card[2][1] == card[2][3] && card[2][3] == card[2][4]) || (card[3][0] == card[3][1] && card[3][1] == card[3][2] && card[3][2] == card[3][3] && card[3][3] == card[3][4])
                || (card[4][0] == card[4][1] && card[4][1] == card[4][2] && card[4][2] == card[4][3] && card[4][3] == card[4][4])) {
        System.out.println("BINGO! Congratulations, you have won!");
        displayBoard(card, card2, card3, card4);
        System.exit(0);
        return false;
    } else if ((card[0][0] == card[1][0] && card[1][0] == card[2][0] && card[2][0] == card[3][0] && card[3][0] == card[4][0]) || (card[0][1] == card[1][1] && card[1][1] == card[2][1] && card[2][1] == card[3][1] && card[3][1] == card[4][1])
                || (card[0][2] == card[1][2] && card[1][2] == card[3][2] && card[3][2] == card[4][2]) || (card[0][3] == card[1][3] && card[1][3] == card[2][3] && card[2][3] == card[3][3] && card[3][3] == card[4][3])
                    || (card[0][4] == card[1][4] && card[1][4] == card[2][4] && card[2][4] == card[3][4] && card[3][4] == card[4][4])) {
        System.out.println("BINGO! Congratulations, you have won!");
        displayBoard(card, card2, card3, card4);
        System.exit(0);
        return false;
    } else if ((card[0][0] == card[1][1] && card[1][1] == card[3][3] && card[3][3]== card[4][4]) || (card[4][0] == card[3][1] && card[3][1] == card[1][3] && card[1][3]== card[0][4])) {
        System.out.println("BINGO! Congratulations, you have won!");
        displayBoard(card, card2, card3, card4);
        System.exit(0);
        return false;
    } else if ((card2[0][0] == card2[0][1] && card2[0][1] == card2[0][2] && card2[0][2] == card2[0][3] && card2[0][3] == card2[0][4]) || (card2[1][0] == card2[1][1] && card2[1][1] == card2[1][2] && card2[1][2] == card2[1][3] && card2[1][3] == card2[1][4])
        || (card2[2][0] == card2[2][1] && card2[2][1] == card2[2][3] && card2[2][3] == card2[2][4]) || (card2[3][0] == card2[3][1] && card2[3][1] == card2[3][2] && card2[3][2] == card2[3][3] && card2[3][3] == card2[3][4])
            || (card2[4][0] == card2[4][1] && card2[4][1] == card2[4][2] && card2[4][2] == card2[4][3] && card2[4][3] == card2[4][4])) {
        System.out.println("BINGO! Congratulations, you have won!");
        displayBoard(card, card2, card3, card4);
        System.exit(0);
        return false;
    } else if ((card2[0][0] == card2[1][0] && card2[1][0] == card2[2][0] && card2[2][0] == card2[3][0] && card2[3][0] == card2[4][0]) || (card2[0][1] == card2[1][1] && card2[1][1] == card2[2][1] && card2[2][1] == card2[3][1] && card2[3][1] == card2[4][1])
        || (card2[0][2] == card2[1][2] && card2[1][2] == card2[3][2] && card2[3][2] == card2[4][2]) || (card2[0][3] == card2[1][3] && card2[1][3] == card2[2][3] && card2[2][3] == card2[3][3] && card2[3][3] == card2[4][3])
            || (card2[0][4] == card2[1][4] && card2[1][4] == card2[2][4] && card2[2][4] == card2[3][4] && card2[3][4] == card2[4][4])) {
        System.out.println("BINGO! Congratulations, you have won!");
        displayBoard(card, card2, card3, card4);
        System.exit(0);
        return false;
    } else if ((card2[0][0] == card2[1][1] && card2[1][1] == card2[3][3] && card2[3][3]== card2[4][4]) || (card2[4][0] == card2[3][1] && card2[3][1] == card2[1][3] && card2[1][3]== card2[0][4])) {
        System.out.println("BINGO! Congratulations, you have won!");
        displayBoard(card, card2, card3, card4);
        System.exit(0);
        return false;
    } else if ((card3[0][0] == card3[0][1] && card3[0][1] == card3[0][2] && card3[0][2] == card3[0][3] && card3[0][3] == card3[0][4]) || (card3[1][0] == card3[1][1] && card3[1][1] == card3[1][2] && card3[1][2] == card3[1][3] && card3[1][3] == card3[1][4])|| (card3[2][0] == card3[2][1] && card3[2][1] == card3[2][3] && card3[2][3] == card3[2][4])
        || (card3[3][0] == card3[3][1] && card3[3][1] == card3[3][2] && card3[3][2] == card3[3][3] && card3[3][3] == card3[3][4])
            || (card3[4][0] == card3[4][1] && card3[4][1] == card3[4][2] && card3[4][2] == card3[4][3] && card3[4][3] == card3[4][4])) {
        System.out.println("CPU CALLS BINGO! YOU LOSE!");
        displayBoard(card, card2, card3, card4);
        System.exit(0);
        return false;
    } 
            }
return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you have written in the `checkWinner` method is quite short, because using loops will give make your code more tedious to work with and it will be a lot longer. But, I have written down the `CheckWinner` method using loops. I haven't ran this code in IDE. So, there maybe some bugs. I hope is helped you.

NOTE:**below code is only implementing for the card method only**

```
public static boolean checkWinner(String[][] card, String[][] card2, String[][] card3, String[][]card4) {

boolean flag = true;
//repeat this nested-loop for card2 and card3 similarly, which I haven't showed in my code.
//The below nested loop are for the condition for the 'if' condition in your code.  
for(int j=0; j<5; j++) {

    boolean flag1 = true;

    for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {

        if (card[i][j] == card[i][j+1]) {



        }

        else {

            flag1 = false;
            break;

        }

    }

    if (flag1) {

        System.out.println("BINGO! Congratulations, you have won!");
        displayBoard(card, card2, card3, card4);
        System.exit(0);
        flag = false;
        break;  

    }

}

if (flag) {

    int i=0, j=0;
    boolean flag2 = true;   
    while (i<5 && j<5) {

        if (i!=2 && j!=2) {

            if (card[i][j]==card[i+1][j+1]) {



`           }

            else flag2 = false;
            break;  

        }

        i++;
        j++;

    }

    if (flag2) {

        System.out.println("BINGO! Congratulations, you have won!");
        displayBoard(card, card2, card3, card4);
        System.exit(0);
        flag = false;               

    }

    else {

        i=4;
        j=0;
        flag2 = true;   
        while (i<5 && j<5) {

            if (i!=2 && j!=2) {

                if (card[i][j]==card[i+1][j+1]) {



    `           }

                else {

                    flag2 = false;
                    break;

                }   

            }

            i--;
            j++;

        }

        if (flag2) {

            System.out.println("BINGO! Congratulations, you have won!");
            displayBoard(card, card2, card3, card4);
            System.exit(0);
            flag = false;           

        }       

    }   

}            

return(flag);
```

}